# How can i make a hyperlink column of a gridview containing pdf or doc files to either open in acrobat reader or in a new tab in browser?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

This is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="MathGridView" Width="1230px" runat="server" CellPadding="20" 
        ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        GridLines="None">
      <Columns>
     <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" DataNavigateUrlFields="Name" DataTextField="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>

      </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

There is one hyperlink column present called Name. Now what i want is when i click any content of name(i.e. Any file with extension .pdf or.doc), I want to open that content in either acrobat reader(in case of pdf) or in a new tab in browser.Here the contents i.e.files are not stored in a database.  How can i do this??

Comment: Where are the files stored then ? Are they in some sub-folder of your web app, or elsewhere on disk ?

Comment: the files are stored in ~/E-library/Books/Math and my application is stored in E-library(i.e. my application name is E-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - what you're missing is pointing the hyperlink to correct location; add this to your asp:HyperLink element:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Books/Math/{0}"
```